# How to detect password change in Post Confirmation Lambda Trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm triggering a Lambda when a user registers to make an entry to a database. Post Confirmation Lambda Trigger triggers fine, there are no problems with it. Now, after implementing a password change form I'm seeing the same Lambda triggered.

In fact, AWS states that it should - it's "Post Confirmation" and so when the user confirms his email retyping sent code, it triggers. I'm fine with that.

How to recognise, in the Lambda, what was the reason for firing the trigger? I don't want to make the same DB calls when it's just a password change.

(I checked the request coming in - there's nothing useful for that problem there)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here..after user submits forgot password..POST_CONFIRMATION trigger is invoked.btw @wiktus239 have you resolved the issue?

Comment: The lambda was creating a user record in DynamoDB and it overwrote the existing one on password change.
I ended up adding a condition to the `dynamodb.put` parameters effectively preventing that: `ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(PK)'` (where PK was primary key with a value of users email).

Comment: So it solved my issue but that's not exactly an answer to my question

Answer (score 13):

To differentiate the source on a **PostConfirmation**, you have to use the `"triggerSource": "string"` attribute in the event object.

The trigger source can be `PostConfirmation_ConfirmForgotPassword` or `PostConfirmation_ConfirmSignUp` for a **PostConfirmation**.

The event object will be of the format:

```
{
    "version": "string",
    "triggerSource": "string",
    "region": AWSRegion,
    "userPoolId": "string",
    "userName": "string",
    "callerContext": 
        {
            "awsSdkVersion": "string",
            "clientId": "string"
        },
    "request":
        {
            "userAttributes": {
                "string": "string",
                ....
            }
        },
    "response": {}
}
```

reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-trigger-sources